# Can I get seamless roaming with a wireless range extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, repeater, wireless-extender

I am using an Amped Wireless REC10 range extender that I have on hand to increase my wireless signal to other parts of the house. The config will let duplicate my network settings exactly down to the SSID and security settings but it will NOT let me change the extended network's channel.

Is it possible to configure this device for seamless romaing, which I doesn't seem to be happening, or do I need to return it and get an actual repeater? Will there be a real difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel really doesn't matter - As long as the SSID and security settings are the same, devices should recognize it as a valid access point to connect to and connect to it if its signal is stronger. In fact changing the channel to match the main AP will cause interference and slow things down.

If devices aren't roaming, it's probably due to the device configuration. Some wireless adapters have a "roaming sensitivity" setting that lets you configure how "eagerly" the adapter will switch to a stronger access point.

If your adapter has such a setting, in Windows you can probably find it in

```
Network and Sharing Center->Change adapter settings->Right click on wireless adapter->Properties->Configure->Advanced tab
```

Look for a property similar to "Roaming sensitivity".

If you can't find one, try installing the manufacturer's driver (instead of using the default Windows driver). If it still doesn't appear, it's probably best to just let it be - it probably means that the difference in signal strength between the main AP and the extender isn't big enough for computers to switch to the extender.

Just curious though - what software are you using to check which access point your computer is connecting to?

Comment: I'm actually using my iPhone and iPad to test. The extender assigns IP addresses and makes itself the DNS server so I check the IP address of the network I'm connected to. The iOS devices seem to hold onto the connection forever. If I restart the wireless (turn it off and on) on the device it'll connect to the nearest network.

Comment: @mikealeonetti Ideally the extender should not be assigning IP addresses; there should only be one LAN and devices connected to the extender should be on the same LAN as devices connected to the main AP. I honestly don't know whether this is contributing to your roaming problem, but it's something you should consider. I did find some forum posts online, however, that suggest that some Apple devices wait until the signal strength is very low before they try to find a new AP. Unfortunately if this is the issue it would not be something you can fix. Perhaps try with a Windows laptop?